# Searching 2D array for specific value in C

Tags: c, arrays, search

I need some help finishing the last part of the assignment. I need to search a specific column of a 2D array for a specific value passed by another array. Once I find the first occurrence, save it to a third array, and then continue to search the next column for a new value.

```
myTEST mySearchArrayIntAll(const int theArray[][aTotItems2], int dataRows, int dataCols, int searchCols[], const int searchVals[])
{
    myTEST fncFlag = bPASS;
    int colCount=0;
    int rowCount=0;
    int index=0;
    int empty=-1;
    int searchVal=0;

        do
        {
            searchVal = searchVals[index];
            for(rowCount=0; rowCount<dataRows-1; rowCount++)
            {

            }

        } while (true);

        return(fncFlag);
}
```

theArray = values to be searched

dataRows = number of actual filled rows in theArray

dataCols = number of actual filled columns in theArray

searchCols[] = set to display column and row of value where it was first found in column ( [col] = row )

searchVals[] = set of values to search for per column... ( [col to search] = value to 
search for)

I'm just not sure how to structure the code to do this each time for each column and I am just a bit burned out... this is just the last function I need to wrap up into my code...

i updated my code with the new for loops and i think this might be what i am going for... let me know what you thing....

```
myTEST mySearchArrayIntAll(const int theArray[][aTotItems2], int dataRows, int dataCols, int searchCols[], const int searchVals[])
{
    myTEST fncFlag = bPASS;
    int colCount=0;
    int rowCount=0;
    int searchVal=0;

        for(colCount=0; colCount<dataCols-1; colCount++)
            {
                searchVal=searchVals[colCount];

                for(rowCount=0; rowCount<dataRows-1; rowCount++)
                {
                    if(searchCols[colCount] == searchVal)
                        rowCount=dataRows;

                    if(theArray[rowCount][colCount] == searchVal)
                        searchCols[colCount] = rowCount;

                }

            }


    return(fncFlag);
}
```

3.0

```
myTEST mySearchArrayIntAll(const int theArray[][aTotItems2], int dataRows, int dataCols, int searchCols[], const int searchVals[])
{
    myTEST fncFlag = bPASS;
    int colCount=0;
    int rowCount=0;
    int searchVal=0;
    int empty=-1;       //searchCols is initalized to -1

        for(colCount=0; colCount<dataCols-1; colCount++)
            {
                searchVal=searchVals[colCount];

                for(rowCount=0; rowCount<dataRows-1; rowCount++)
                {
                    if(searchCols[colCount] != empty)
                        rowCount=dataRows;

                    if(theArray[rowCount][colCount] == searchVal)
                        searchCols[colCount] = rowCount;

                }

            }

    return(fncFlag);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: It's fairly clear that you need a `for` loop to search each column in turn, and another nested `for` loop to scan down the rows. The rest is a simple question of data shuffling, making sure you test the right values, and save them in the correct places. In general, assume that `do ... while (...);` means you are doing it wrong. That isn't an absolute rule, but 95% of the time (I was tempted to say 99%, but that might be exaggerating), top-checked loops (`while` or `for`) are correct. The specification is incomplete: it doesn't cover what to do if the value is not found, nor the return value.

Comment: ok, sry was eating... yea i had 2 for loops started and then was a little bothered by something... i see how im going to be doing it but what i am wondering is how i can exit the for loop once the value is found... say their are 85 rows in a column and i find the value i need on row 8... i do not need to go any further for that particular row... could i nest an if statement in the inner for loop to do a check for whether the number as been found?

Comment: The `break` statement is the obvious, standard way to exit a loop early.

Comment: OK; if you're not allowed to use `break`, you probably aren't allowed to use `goto` or `continue` either.  So, in that case, you'll probably set a flag to true before entering the loop and add `&& flag` to the loop condition, and set the flag to false when you've found your value. And bad luck on being made to write Pascal in C.  What you suggested — nesting an `if` inside the loop — would also work, but you'd really like the loop to stop rather than skip over the body.

Comment: well if you look up i added a couple new makes... i added the `if` to my loop and it is true that it most likely does check the next row i feel it will be find... all the `if` statement check is if the next `if` statement found what it was looking for and set a value in the answer array (it is initiated to -1) so it is checking for whether it is -1 or not, if it is changed, it resets the index value to the max thus exiting the loop when finished... and you are right, no goto's line calls... etc...

Answer (score 0):

This code is a minor adaptation of yours, primarily fixing off-by-one limits in the search loops, and using an alternative to `break` to terminate the the inner loop when a match is found.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef bool myTEST;

enum { aTotItems2 = 50 };
enum { bPASS = true };

extern myTEST mySearchArrayIntAll(const int theArray[][aTotItems2], int dataRows,
                           int dataCols, int searchCols[], const int searchVals[]);
myTEST mySearchArrayIntAll(const int theArray[][aTotItems2], int dataRows,
                           int dataCols, int searchCols[], const int searchVals[])
{
    myTEST fncFlag = bPASS;

    for (int colCount = 0; colCount < dataCols; colCount++)
    {
        for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < dataRows; rowCount++)
        {
            if (theArray[rowCount][colCount] == searchVals[colCount])
            {
                searchCols[colCount] = rowCount;
                rowCount = dataRows;
            }
        }
    }

    return(fncFlag);
}

int main(void)
{
    int const data[][50] =
    {
        { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, },
        { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, },
        { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, },
        { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, },
    };
    int rows = 6;
    int cols = 5;
    int search[] = { 6, 8, 7, 4, 9, };
    int found[5] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, };
    int wanted[5] = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 0 };
    (void)mySearchArrayIntAll(data, rows, cols, found, search);
    int fail = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        const char *pass_fail = "PASS";
        if (found[i] != wanted[i])
        {
            pass_fail = "FAIL";
            fail++;
        }
        printf("%d: found %d, wanted %d (%s)\n", i, found[i], wanted[i],
                pass_fail);
    }
    if (fail == 0)
        printf("== PASS ==\n");
    else
        printf("!! FAIL !! (%d tests failed)\n", fail);
    return (fail == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Test results:

```
0: found 3, wanted 3 (PASS)
1: found 1, wanted 1 (PASS)
2: found 2, wanted 2 (PASS)
3: found 5, wanted 5 (PASS)
4: found 0, wanted 0 (PASS)
== PASS ==
```

The interface to the function is cock-eyed; there is one output parameter, and it should be the last — using the convention 'input parameters, then output parameters'.  The return value is completely pointless too.  I left it, but the function should return `void` since it always returns the same value, so there is no point in testing the value, so there is no point in returning it and making the calling code test it.